# Frozen desktop on Dell XPS 14 ultrabook

Tags: 12.04, dell, bumblebee, xps, ultrabook

I have a problem with my novel installation of Ubuntu. Sometimes, the system crashes: the monitor still show the desktop environment, but it is frozen or blocked and the only think that I can do is to press the power button and shot down.

It there a way to understand which kind of problem is? Driver Video, perhaps? How can I do a better diagnosis?

The system is Ubuntu Precise, installed on a Dell XPS 14 Ultrabook, whith Sputinik kernel and Bumblebee drivers for the Nvidia card.

Thanks!!!

Comment: I had the same problem.

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment. I probably fixed the problem and then I forgot my question here! see the answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Ubuntu distribution after Pangolin has not the same problem. Now I am using Mint 14 "Nadia" based on Ubuntu Quantal, and it works.

I suggest you to upgrade your system.

OFF TOPIC I have only a problem with the microfone... :(

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue of Graphic Card Driver or any other driver , its just happens sometimes like when changing main Sound volume or sometimes changing brightness .

It happens often when you have pluged in a usb hub, or any device which most of the time disconnects .

the only thing you can do is press Alt+PrtSc+R+E+I+S+U+B to restart.

there are no fixed proved cause of this issue.